# I'm trying to create foreign key between two tables but got: ORA-02270

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl

Maybe I'm burnout, but I don't understand this. I have two tables in Oracle: TBL_a and TBL_x. I'm trying to create a foreign key between thos two tables as follows and get error

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_a (
    cod_op integer, 
    cod_dni char(8), 
    cod_correl integer, 
     varchar2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_x (
    cod_op integer, 
    cod_dni char(8), 
    blabla varchar2(50)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TBL_A_PK ON TBL_A (COD_OP);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TBL_x_PK ON TBL_x (COD_OP);

ALTER TABLE TBL_a ADD CONSTRAINT TBL_a_R01 
    FOREIGN KEY (COD_OP) REFERENCES TBL_x (COD_OP);
```

Comment: the error is pretty clear convert `cod_op integer` to `cod_op integer primary key` within creation of `tbl_x` table(a foreign key needs a unique or primary key to be able to be created ).

Answer (score 1):

The table that is referred by the foreign key (here, `tbl_x`) must have a primary key or a unique constraint.

In your use case, as you are declaring a unique index on `cod_op`, you could simply make `cod_op` the primary key of `tbl_x` instead: that would make the error disappear.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d80e4c09dae8937f541997a614dc487)**

In general, it is a good practice to have a primary key on any table. Extending the principe of turning your unique indexes to primary keys, your DDL statements could be simplified as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_x (
    cod_op INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    cod_dni CHAR(8), 
    blabla VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_a (
    cod_op INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    cod_dni CHAR(8), 
    cod_correl INTEGER, 
    blabla VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT TBL_a_R01 FOREIGN KEY (COD_OP) REFERENCES TBL_x (COD_OP)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f89555b46fa09b01e49f652352eee07)**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've created unique INDEXES on your tables, but you didn't create a unique or primary key CONSTRAINT. Oracle requires that the constraints exist in order to establish a foreign key relationship.

If you drop your existing indexes and add the appropriate constraints you can establish your foreign key relationship:

```
DROP INDEX TBL_A_PK;

DROP INDEX TBL_x_PK;

ALTER TABLE TBL_A
  ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_A
    UNIQUE(COD_OP)
    USING INDEX;

ALTER TABLE TBL_X
  ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_X
    UNIQUE(COD_OP)
    USING INDEX;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a2ac04370a20d4f4309e04333956811e)